# what is the default pingTimeout and pingInterval in socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I just want to know what is the default value of pingTimeout and PingInterval in socket.io? I read in the docs the values to be:

```
  pingTimeout (Number): how many ms without a pong packet to consider the connection closed (60000)
  pingInterval (Number): how many ms before sending a new ping packet (25000).
```

are these the default values?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Update 12/25/2021: socket.io docs now show that default pingTimeout is 20000 ms (20 sec) as of v4

---

The default values of the pingTimeout have changed from version 2.x to 3.x to 4.x, the current 4.x according to the documentation is:

- pingTimeout: 20000ms  (20 sec)
- pingInterval: 25000ms (25 sec)

You can set those differently if you choose.  Given that you are referring to the latest version of socket.io (version 4) and the docs at https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-options/#pingtimeout

Comment: okay. So if i am right when the server sends two pingPacket at the gaps of 25secs and doesnt recieve any pongPacket in return , then post 10 secs of 50th second, that particular socket connection will be closed. Am i right?

Comment: @roh_dev that would be correct, I believe at one time it was 60/30 for the default, but that left for little tolerance for delay. If you want a more persistent connection you can either increase the timeout, or lower the interval. I should note from the docs, "a client may have to wait up to pingTimeout + pingInterval ms before getting a disconnect event."

Comment: Just an FYI to anyone coming across this answer but the newest version of socket.io has a default pingTimeout of 5000 ms (5 sec) per the docs linked to in this answer.

Comment: The link is broken. Do you have a replacement?

Comment: @theknightD2 - updated the link and the answer, as the latest v4 the default has changed again.

Answer (score 0):

For "socket.io": "^2.1.1",  pingInterval is 60 sec and latest chrome is also becoming ideal at 60 sec so if you have old socket.io package at server then u need to set pingInterval set as 25 sec to work it correctly

Comment: check this https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-protocol#difference-between-v3-and-v4